# Gridview rowcommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a little problem when I go to my gridview in website my button for row command doesn't work. I don't know why.

This is my code for the page:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.CommandName == "Ver")
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow selectedRow = GridView1.Rows[index];

            Session["Imagem"] = GridView1.DataKeys[index]["Imagem"];
            Session["Nome"] = GridView1.DataKeys[index]["Nome"];
            Session["Preço"] = GridView1.DataKeys[index]["Preço"];
            Session["Descricao"] = GridView1.DataKeys[index]["Descricao"];
            Session["Categoria"] = GridView1.DataKeys[index]["Categoria"];
            Session["id"] = GridView1.DataKeys[index]["Id"];
            Session["estado"] = GridView1.DataKeys[index]["estado"];
              GridView1.DataBind();
            Response.Redirect("Detalhes.aspx");
      }
}
```

And my gridview markup is this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
     DataKeyNames="Imagem ,Nome,Preço,Descricao,Categoria,id,estado" 
     DataSourceID="SqlShop" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
     BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None" 
     BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" style="margin-top: 0px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Imagem" SortExpression="Imagem">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Imagem") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Imagem") %>' Height="8%" Width="8%" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Nome" HeaderText="Nome" SortExpression="Nome" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Preço" HeaderText="Preço" SortExpression="Preço" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Descricao" HeaderText="Descricao" SortExpression="Descricao" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Categoria" HeaderText="Categoria" SortExpression="Categoria" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Select" Text="ver" />
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#EDF6F6" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0D4AC4" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D6DFDF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#002876" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlShop" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Produtos]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Your command name is `Select` but your are looking for `Ver` in your code behind. Can you tell if you are getting into the `GridView1_RowCommand` ?

Answer (score 4):

Command name is incorrect in the C# code

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Select") //this part
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            ...
            ...
            Response.Redirect("Detalhes.aspx");
        }

    }
```

Or
You can change the values `ButtonField` parameters as

```
    <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="ver" Text="Select" />
```